# Distorted corner radius on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following code, and the orientation works well when it loads but when the orientation is changed it gets distorted, that is if it loads in portrait and change to landscape, the corner radius gets distorted, like it changes from circle to square.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = categoryCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCVC", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

    cell.catLabel.text = cities[indexPath.row].name
    cell.catImg.image = UIImage(named:cities[indexPath.row].image)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.layer.frame.size.height/2
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2

    return cell
}
```

How to avoid this from happening? Is there a way to call `cellForItemAt indexpath` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and then configuring `corner radius` there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{

    self.collectionView.reloadData()

    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```